# swift 1.2 override prepareForDeletion in NSManagedObject extension

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, swift

Overriding the function `prepareForDeletion` fails in swift 1.2

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import CoreData

extension NSManagedObject {
    @objc func prepareForDeletion() {
        println("deleting object")
    }
}
```

> Error: method 'prepareForDeletion()' with Objective-C selector
>   'prepareForDeletion' conflicts with previous declaration with the same
>   Objective-C selector

```
@objc func prepareForDeletion() {
           ^
```

> CoreData.NSManagedObject:31:14: note: 'prepareForDeletion' previously
>   declared here

```
@objc func prepareForDeletion()
```

Does anyone have an idea?

thanks
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* override a method in a class in an extension of the same class, doing so was always undefined behaviour.

For overriding Objective-C methods in Swift this went unnoticed in
Xcode 6.2 and is now properly diagnosed in Xcode 6.3 beta.

Note that the corresponding practice in Objective-C – 
overriding methods in an Objective-C extension of the same class –
 is also not allowed, see
 ["Avoid Category Method Name Clashes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html):

> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method
>   in the original class, or a method in another category on the same
>   class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which
>   method implementation is used at runtime. This is less likely to be an
>   issue if you’re using categories with your own classes, but can cause
>   problems when using categories to add methods to standard Cocoa or
>   Cocoa Touch classes.

What you can do is to to override the method in your custom
`NSManagedObject` *subclasses*.