# Override controlAlternatingRowBackgroundColors in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm trying to figure out how to override controlAlternatingRowBackgroundColors in Swift but whatever I do I seem to get an error.

```
extension NSColor {

    class var controlAlternatingRowBackgroundColors: [NSColor] {

        return [NSColor.red, NSColor.blue]

    }

}
```

This gives me "Getter for 'controlAlteratingRowBackgroundColors' with Objective-C selector 'controlAlteratingRowBackgroundColors' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector.

If I use override then I get an error saying that it doesn't override anything.

If I create a category on NSColor in objective c it all works as expected!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528099/swift-1-2-override-preparefordeletion-in-nsmanagedobject-extension: You *cannot* override a property in an extension (and doing so in an Objective-C category is *undefined behaviour*).

Comment: Yep, thanks. That looks very similar. Unfortunately it doesn't look this there's any way of doing this then I have nothing to subclass in this instance.